# How to integrate JMX with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jmx, spring-jmx

I have simple class about JMX:
Interface HelloMBean:

```
public interface HelloMBean {
    public void    sayHello();
    public String getName();
    public void    setName(String name);
    public String conCat(String s1, String s2);
}
```

Class Hello implements from interface HelloMBean:

```
import javax.management.AttributeChangeNotification;
import javax.management.Notification;
import javax.management.NotificationBroadcasterSupport;

public class Hello extends NotificationBroadcasterSupport implements HelloMBean {

    private String m_name;

    @Override
    public void sayHello() {

        System.out.print("I say hello");
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {

        Notification n = new AttributeChangeNotification(
                this, 0, 
                System.currentTimeMillis(),
                "My name is changed", 
                "setName", "String", m_name, name);
                sendNotification(n);
                m_name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String conCat(String s1, String s2) {

        return null;
    }

}
```

Then, I create a class client:

```
import javax.management.JMX;
import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;

public class HelloClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
         JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:7271/Hello");
         JMXConnector cn = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
         MBeanServerConnection msc = cn.getMBeanServerConnection();
         ObjectName helloObjName = new ObjectName("com:service=Hello1");
         HelloMBean hello = JMX.newMBeanProxy(msc, helloObjName, HelloMBean.class);
         hello.sayHello();
         System.out.println(hello.conCat("I am", " a hello mbean"));
         Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

And class Server:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorServer;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorServerFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;


public class HelloMain {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
       MBeanServer ms = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
       ObjectName helloMBName = new ObjectName("com:service=Hello1");
       Hello hello = new Hello();
       ms.registerMBean(hello, helloMBName);
       JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(
               "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:7271/Hello");
       JMXConnectorServer cs = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, null, ms);
       cs.start();//
       Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE); 
   }
}
```

Affter using rmiregistry 7271. I have create simple client and server using JMX. But I can't integrate JMX with Spring (JMX handled with Spring). I have try but unsuccessful. Have any solution for it??

Answer (score 4):

It's much easier to just let [Spring manage JMX for you](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html).

Comment: can you post file beans.xml. I have a problem about it.

Comment: Your question is imprecise; it's not at all clear what you are asking for. You need to explain exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GaryRussell I've just read your answer. I am following your link. Maybe you will be able to help with this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22789428/1021970